# Java and Bluetooth - totally dead?

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

I've planned to do a program where text messages are sent from an Android phone to a computer. I thought it would be simple to use Bluetooth but no. I can't find any material from these days. All of them are from years back and doesn't seem to work.

I found something about Bluecove. I downloaded the library and included in my project. Well, doesn't seem to be up to date. The latest one is from 2010 (snapshot, stable from 2008) and doesn't even work on 64 bit system!

I've also planned to develop it further in the future to also include answering phone calls on PC. Is there any way to get Bluetooth working in this situation or do I have to do tricks with internet?

Comment: If you vote for closing, please comment why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by adding all the four jar files from [here](http://snapshot.bluecove.org/distribution/download/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.63/) into the project.